# How do I make link to display the data on browser instead of downloading?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, google-chrome-extension

This [link](https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=hi&dt=t&dt=t&q=hello)

downloads the f.txt file when clicked. I want it to display the data directly on the browser.

Ex: On clicking this [link](https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=trnsl.1.1.20170222T005237Z.c822f17f30208ee9.7df12d4944735ac8d985d500634196b9155dcbc0&text=hello&lang=hi)

it displays the data on the browser.

I have thought of another method though i.e. downloading and loading the data but it takes user time and slow down my application.

So is there any way that I can make that link to show the data on the browser?

Comment: Change the file extension to .html or .json  (ex: f.html or f.json) - by default, .txt files will always download.

Comment: Is this question about writing a Chrome extension to make this change? Or, are you asking how to configure Chrome to do this (without writing code)? Or, are you asking for us to provide a pointer to a Chrome extension which does this for you?

Comment: Not sure if that's the case but you may display your .txt file in the browser via HTML DOM's `.innerhtml` property.

Comment: I want to write for my chrome extension. The above 1st link downloads when requested and I want to load that data without letting the user download.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the Web server is serving the file.  If the MIME type is text/plain, it will display in the browser.  If it's something like application/octet-stream, the browser will prompt the user to download the file.